# more_like_this and group by

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to combine more_like_this and aggregations to get similar documents and show them grouped ? Can I do that in Elasticsearch ?

```
{
  "size": 12,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": [
            "summary_text", "description.orig"
          ],
          "docs": [
            {
              "_id": "9753"
            }enter code here
          ],
          "min_term_freq": 1,
          "max_query_terms": 12
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_product_class": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_class_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In Elasticsearch 2.3 you aggregation should look something like:

```
{
  "size": 12,
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": ["summary_text", "description.orig"],
      "like": [{
          "_index": "youIndex",
          "_type": "yourType",
          "_id": "9753"
        }],
      "min_term_freq": 1,
      "max_query_terms": 12
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_product_class": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_class_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can specify multiple documents in the `"like"` array or even define docs on the fly using `"doc": {"field1": x, "field2": y, ...}`. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) is a good reference.

Comment: aggregation will only show the group counts by that field, it doesn't actually group the results from the more_like_this page. There is no mention of grouping in that reference.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe I misinterpreted the question.